# Grep -> How to replace contents of a text file

Tags: perl, text, replace, grep

I have a text file that has a lot of lines and it is laid out like

```
zzzzz | id@host.tld |
yyyyy | id@host.tld |
```

one of these per line for about 10 million lines.

using a Grep expression, how can I do a replace to just get

```
zzzzz
yyyyy
```

etc for each line in the file

Maybe using Perl to rewrite out the file would be fine too, I just dont know a lot of Perl.

UPDATE 1: Sometimes the export gets run to produce:

```
id@host.tld | zzzzz
id@host.tld | yyyyy
```

UPDATE 2: Sometimes they leave row numbers in as:

```
a variable digit row number | zzzzz | id@host.tld |
a variable digit row number | yyyyy | id@host.tld |
```

UPDATE 3: This file can contain lines with formats like:

```
zzzzz | id@host.tld |
yyyyy | id@host.tld |
id@host.tld | zzzzz
id@host.tld | yyyyy
variable digit row number | zzzzz | id@host.tld |
variable digit row number | yyyyy | id@host.tld |
```

Comment: Please explain, do you want the same file, but remove email addresses, or to remove the expressions before the email addresses?

Comment: Hmmm .... Did you edit your question or did i just misread it the first time around?

Comment: Well, anyways i replaced my answer and deleted my old

Comment: @Sai - no i did indeed edit once I noticed the line breaks did not happen. I am sorry to make you think you were crazy

Comment: @mu is too short - yes, exactly variable order although this tends to be the 3 ways the departments put the data in for this. Shame indeed, all I can do though is try to make it easy for me to parse it for yet a 4th department that needs it

Answer (score 5):

It can be done using (GNU) `grep`, too:

```
grep -o '^[^|]*'
```

*Edit*:
If you don't want trailing spaces but want to allow leading spaces resp. spaces in the middle of the first field, you could change the command to:

```
grep -o '^[^|]*[^| ]'
```

Comment: You leave some trailing whitespace behind (which may or may not be a problem). But +1 for making it happen with just `grep`.

Comment: @mu is too short: I added one character to my pattern (will work if the text field does not include spaces).

Comment: But can you make it work with only `grep` if there are spaces in the first field?

Comment: Nice, your grep-Fu is strong. Shame that the question keeps changing though.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) |.*| \(.*\) |.*|/\1 \2/' filename
```

or

```
sed 's/ |[^|]*|//g' filename
```

**EDIT:**
The revised question is even easier:

```
sed 's/ |.*//' filename
```

You might even be able to get away with

```
sed 's/ .*//' filename
```

but that's really pushing it.

Comment: Don't down vote this answer -- the question changed; probably was not formatted correctly initially.

Comment: @Sai: (Thanks, very sporting of you!)

Answer (score 2):

Seemed like the question got edited -- or maybe i am losing it :) If all you need is the first part till the "|" something like the following should work

```
sed 's/\([^|]*\).*/\1/' filename.txt
```

Comment: do you have a good tutorial on `sed` I was able to use the above to output to a new file, but now I want to run some commands on the file again to help with Update 1 and Update 2 above.

Comment: You can take a look at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html -- if you can get your hands on the O'Reilly book on Sed and Awk that will be useful too.

Comment: is there a way to `sed` for something like `23 |` to be more specific a 2 digit number (exactly two digits) followed by a space followed by a | and then replace with nothing so those are gone? I am trying to think of ways to use the power I am discovering!

Comment: You can try something like `sed 's/[0-9][0-9] |//'`

Answer (score 1):

with perl...for huge files...

```
use Tie::File;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', 'file.path/file.name' || die;

for (@array) {
    s/^([^\|]+).*/$1/;
}

untie @array;
```

Comment: what constitutes a big file in terms of MB?

Comment: = What about the updates I posted above where the file could be written a few different ways and I want to create a single perl script to parse each line, decide what format it is in and output the 'zzzzzzz' field.

Comment: @ABOB - Depends! But I wouldn't load 10M lines in memory unless for a good reason or a short time!!

Comment: @ABOB - take a look at this [link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)! with  s/^([^\|]+).*/$1/; you will get "all until the first |".

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -e 'while(<>) { /^(.+?) |/ && print "$1\n" }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Should work flawlessly, unless the first entry may contain `|`.

Comment: what about the updates I posted above where the file could be written a few different ways and I want to create a single perl script to parse each line, decide what format it is in and output the 'zzzzzzz' field. Your one liner does work on my original test case.

Comment: @ABOB Well, in that case, you're going to have to give us some rules about the 'zzzzz' field. Is it only a-z letters? What characters can be in there?

Comment: `zzzzz` can be most any character as it represents a key/password so to speak.

Comment: see Update 3 for a comprehensive idea.

Comment: @ABOB "any character" means it can be numbers or `|` or `id@host.tld`, which means your regex can never be completely reliable. In other words, you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty simple in perl.

You can do a split on " | " to get an array for each line. Then open a file to write, and write "$array[0]\n"

Your program would look something like:

```
open IN, '<', "someFile.txt";
@lines = <IN>;
close IN;

open OUT, '>', "outfile.txt";

foreach(@lines){
   chomp;
   @array = split /\s*\|\s*/, $_;
   print OUT $array[0] . "\n";
}
close OUT;
```

For your updates:

[Split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a function that takes a pattern, an expression and returns an array of strings. So in the example above. The pattern is a regular expression. \s is a space, \| is "|". So it's saying split on a space zero or more times (\s*), a pipe (\|) and zero or more spaces (\s*).

Update 1 would look like:

```
@array = {
           [0] => "id@host.com"
           [1] => "zzzzzzzzzz"
         }
```

Update 2 would look like:

```
@array = {
           [0] => "some Number"
           [1] => "zzzzzzzzzz"
           [2] => "id@host.com"
         }
```

Comment: @Nate - I get a few errors for lines 9 and 10. Is it something to do with the '' in the split, the lines dont seem to tokenize in my editor but I dont see the offending item

Comment: The line with split should read: my $array = split /\s*\|\s*/;

Comment: @pavel - Thanks, that results in `Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated at pw.pl line 11.` and `No comma allowed after filehandle at pw.pl line 12.`

Comment: this is a bad way to parse a text file with 10 million lines! Tie::File module should be used in such cases!

Comment: @ABOB Oops! I fixed the answer... as for the error, I changed $array = split.., to @array = split... The way I had it, I was clobbering @_. I think sed is the way to go though.

Comment: Nate - can you explain the split a bit? Second, what if the format changed to some to my UPDATE1 above? What about UPDATE2? Multiple foreach loops, each handling the case. if I understand the split, I think I could accomplish this

Comment: @Nate - I get a `no comma allowed after file handle on` on line 13 `print OUT, $array[0] . "\n";` I looked up the syntax and removing the comma after `OUT` works

Comment: @ABOB Updated to try and explain split a little more, hope that helped

Comment: @Nate - I think so, so really to create one perl script depending upon how this file is created, inside the `foreach` I need to split each line, test how many positions it has and then print OUT the correct position.

Comment: @Nate - so it seems that i could check to see if `array[0]` or `array[2]` contain an `@` then output `array[1]` otherwise it fits my original format I posted and output `array[0]`

Comment: @Nate - the downfall here is it zzzzzz or yyyy have an @ in them which does happen periodically.. darn random data from 3rd party...

Comment: @Nate You can't load 10 million lines into a single array, you will get memory issues. Also, why do this whole procedure for something that only requires a one-liner?

Comment: @ABOB - TLP and cirne100 are correct, you should use Tie::File